# How can I include all the other fields of table when I'm filtering the data by only 1 field using group by hand having?

Tags: sql, filter, group-by, count, having

So this my query below:

```
select creditcard
from  user where preferred_card = '1'
and uder_identification_code = 'creditcard' 
group by creditcard having count (1) > 1;
```

So I'm trying to get list of all the user having more than 1 credit card as their preferred card(basically it's a data clean up since there should only 1 preferred).

But since I'm doing group by and having count, when I tried to put in other fields, the query doesn't run because logic error. How do I make the query show other fields, like lastname, dob from the user table? I'm trying to pull all the list of users so I can do data clean up.

all the changes failed below:

```
select creditcard, lastname
from  user where preferred_card = '1'
and uder_identification_code = 'creditcard' 
group by creditcard having count (1) > 1 and lastname;`



select *
from  user where preferred_card = '1'
and uder_identification_code = 'creditcard' 
group by creditcard having count (1) > 1 and lastname;
```

I've tried group by by more than several fields from the same table

Comment: Move lastname to group by?

Comment: You should add other fields to GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the table with the data you get from group by as such:

```
select * from user
where creditcard in 
(select creditcard 
from  user 
where preferred_card = '1' and uder_identification_code = 'creditcard'  
group by creditcard having count (1) > 1);
```